Cómo se corrige el error de sintaxis sql generado
Tengo el siguiente error cuando quiero generar el script sql desde Workbench luego de crear el modelo ER, el error apunta exactamente a los campos que están como fk o Foren Key.
Error code: 1064 usted tiene un error en su sintaxis sql cheque el manual correspondiente para su versión de servidor MariaDb para la sintaxis correcta cerca CONSTRAINT 'idCliente' FOREIGN KEY ('idCliente') REFERENCES 'mydb' en línea 8.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`cliente` (
  `idcliente` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Nombres` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Apellidos` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Correo` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idcliente`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`productos`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`productos` (
  `idproducto` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `producto` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `unidades` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `preciopublico` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `idCliente` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idproducto`),
  INDEX `idCliente_idx` (`idCliente` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `idCliente`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idCliente`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`cliente` (`idcliente`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;



En realidad no detecto cuál es el error. Mil gracias por su apoyo.
Deseo conocer como puedo solucionar este error.

Si estás generando el código desde Workbench para importar en PhpMyAdmin con MariaDB, solo elimina la palabra VISIBLE de las consultas.

Perfecto, mil gracias, solucionado.
